# Raspberry Pi Feature Requests?

Tags: official-foundation

Is there any place where the user base/community can submit feature requests to the Raspberry Pi Foundation?

I would like to submit the idea that in addition to PXE (upcoming feature in future hardware) these things would literally take over the planet if there was a POE (power over ethernet) variant.

While the intent of the project seems to be to provide a low cost way to introduce people to programming, finding commercial and industrial uses for something drives sales, which increases production volume which in turn lowers cost and in turn only serves to make them even more accessible.

Comment: Better yet: Make yourself rich by patenting a POE adapter (POE cable in, 5v + eth out).

Comment: PoE has been requested many times.  If and when it can be done at the same price point it will be implemented.

Comment: I can build them with these and a GPIO socket - http://www.semiconductorstore.com/cart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=48549

Answer (score 2):

While this site has a great community, it's **not** official to the actual Raspberry Pi Foundation in any way and they pay us little attention.

My suggestion would be to try the official forum over at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/. More specifically, I would suggest the [General Discussion](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=63) board.

Comment: Also writing the request down on a piece of paper, placing it in a glass (not plastic) bottle, corking it, and throwing it in the Atlantic may eventually grant your wish.

Comment: @goldilocks Don't do that. Apart from all plastic waste already swimming in the oceans, a somewhat bigger fish might swallow that bottle causing severe injuries when the stomach muscles smash it.